# Deployed app to Heroku but images did not change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm somewhat of a Heroku noob but I just deployed my app to Heroku, the text that I entered changed, but the images did not. I've deployed this same app several times before and have had no problems like this until now. I've double checked and the image that I want to be on the live version is in the assets/images folder. What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: you may clean the cache on your browser.

Comment: I tried that. Still the same result. Would precompiling have anything to do with it?

Comment: Yes.  If you precompiled assets once and then changed images, you must precompile again.  (Of course I'm assuming you have images in /assets.)

Comment: I thought Heroku complies assets automatically?

Comment: It does unless you precompile yourself.  Then it accepts your pushed, precompiled assets as correct.  You can tell by watching the slug build. If it never mentions "compiling assets," then it has accepted yours.

Comment: I accidentally precompiled earlier in the day (didn't know what I was doing), is there anyway to make it go back to precompiling automatically?

Comment: Delete everything from public/assets

Comment: Can you provide more details in your question about what you changed and why you expect images to change because of it?